# Can a function pointer typedef be forward declared in C?

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef, forward-declaration

The title says it all! Can it be done and if so, how?

---

A little background if you must know: We've recently taken over a project from another team (because they were disbanded) that has strongly interdependent headers. Changing that is difficult without yanking stuff out of the header file they logically belong in and stuffing somewhere else, where it does not logically belong.

Until now, the approach to deal with this has been to simply forward declare structs and functions from other headers where necessary. That worked fairly well until we got into the typedef'd function pointers, which is how our callback function types are currently implemented.

We would like to solve this without having to disturb the logic of the header files if possible, but have been unable to forward declare those typedefs to far. Various searches for 'forward declare typedef' only yielded results about forward declaring typedef'd structs, which doesn't help us at all.

---

Example:

a.h

```
/* @file a.h */
#ifndef _a_
#define _a_

#include "b.h"

// Definitions that need stuff from b.h

typedef void (some_callback_function) (uint32_t, uint16_t, uint8_t*);

// More definitions that need stuff from b.h
#endif
```

b.h:

```
/* @file b.h */
#ifndef _b_
#define _b_

#include "a.h"

// Definitions that need stuff from a.h

struct some_struct {
    // Stuff
    some_callback_function *cb_someting; // ERROR: some_callback_function not defined yet!
    // Other stuff
};

// More definitions that need stuff from a.h
#endif
```

---

**EDIT**: In this example, the problem arises when including `a.h`. The first thing it does before declaring anything itself in including `b.h`, which in turn also includes `a.h` before declaring anything. The guards prevent an endless loop here, but I still end up with `a.h` trying to declare something using stuff that will later be declared in `b.h` but has not yet been. Thus a forward declaration should does the trick for structs and functions.

If typedefs cannot be forward declared, I could think of two ugly workarounds:

- Remove the includes from the header files and leave it up to the user to include the other headers. As far as I know, this is considered bad coding styles as headers should include their dependencies themselves.
- Move the typedefs before the #includes. I am not sure whether this is actually bad style, but my intuition tells me that putting anything before the #includes is evil. Also, this only works as long as the typedefs do not need anything from another header file.

Comment: Post example code.

Comment: What would you consider a *forward declaration* of a function pointer type?

Comment: Most probably, the answer is *no*....

Comment: No it's not possible to only declare a type-alias using `typedef`. With `typedef` you *define* a type-alias.

Comment: Why not move `typedef void (some_callback_function) (uint32_t, uint16_t, uint8_t*);` before `// Definitions that need stuff from b.h` as the typedef does not need stuff from b?

Comment: @chux, Unfortunately, that wouldn't help. See my edit at the bottom of the post. Basically, I'd have to move it before the #include, which seems really ugly to me.

Comment: The typedef simply needs to appear before the struct definition. You can move it there or you can duplicate it (only since C11), it's up to you.

Comment: This often happens in older systems that try to align headers  with code, which was thought a good pattern at one time but fails on mutual deps as you've discovered. That a includes b and vice versa is an immediate code smell. Suggest you merge the two into a single file, reorder until dependencies are met, then if necessary look for the new best way to decompose into smaller headers. This kind of refactoring is normally quite safe if you move only typedefs.

Comment: @Antagonym [It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883368/can-a-function-pointer-typedef-be-forward-declared-in-c?noredirect=1#comment78731272_45883368) does help.  `some_callback_function`  does not depend on `b.h` so it can occur before `#include "b.h"

// Definitions that need stuff from b.h` pair.

Comment: "anything before the #includes is evil.' is true because code has a cyclic dependency otherwise.  A way around this is to put `some_callback_function` in its own `c.h` file.  Fundamentally without showing more of code, this is academic.